# Confirmação de preenchimento de formulário html ionic 4

Tags: javascript, ionic4

meu app tem um formulário de endereço, que busca todos os dados pelo cep, mas ele precisa colocar o numero manualmente, porem atualmente, o usuario pode confirmar sem preencher o numero, sou novo nisso, como eu posso validar isso, uso o ionic 4, pensei em fazer uma função de validação no javaScript mas nao sei como implementa-la

Comment: Qual é o código do formulário? Inclua-o na pergunta clicando em "editar".

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite amigo,
Existe uma biblioteca no ionic que se chama formControl.

Da uma estudada nela, segue link a respeito dela

```
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/a-good-form-validation-example/117960
```

eu faria um exemplo porem no momento estou sem tempo.

Lembrando que você tem que importar do @angularForm e instaicala para utilizar no seu projeto.

Boa sorte, qualquer coisa estou aqui, desulpe por nao poder fazer o exemplo no momento.

Comment: Talvez ele não esteja utilizando Ionic com Angular.